# How do I correlate telemetryClient.TrackException(ex) to its containing telemetryClient.StartOperation(...)?

Tags: exception, error-logging, telemetry, appinsights

In this code sample, I am attempting to correlate the `TrackException()` call to its containing `StartOperation()` by providing a `properties` dictionary of (what I think are) the appropriate correlation ids.

```
public void MyMethod()
{
    using (var operation = telemetryClient.StartOperation<DependencyTelemetry>("MyMethod"))
    {
         try
         {
             ...
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
             telemetryClient.TrackException(ex, new Dictionary<string, string>
             {
                 {"operation_Id", operation.Telemetry.Context.Operation.Id },
                 {"operation_ParentId", operation.Telemetry.Id}
             });
         }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work.  I do get the exceptions in AppInsights, but they are not associated with the operation that caused them to be thrown.  I would appreciate thoughts on what might be wrong.  Thanks.